# How to break $\frac{1}{(1+(x+iy))^2}$ into real and imaginary parts?

Tags: complex-numbers

What techniques might I employ to separate it?

edit

$$ (1+(x-iy))^2=((1+x)-iy)^2 = (1+x)^2-2(1+x)yi-y^2$$
$$(1+(x+iy))^2=((1+x)+iy))^2=(1+x)^2+2(1+x)yi-y^2$$

$$\frac{1}{1+(x+iy))^2}=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2+2(1+x)yi-y^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2+2(1+x)yi-y^2} +\frac{(1+x)^2-2(1+x)yi-y^2}{(1+x)^2-2(1+x)yi-y^2}=\frac{(1+x)^2-2(1+x)yi-y^2}{2(1+x)^2-2y^2}$$
$$Re= \frac{(1+x)^2-y^2}{2(1+x)^2-2y^2}$$
$$Im=\frac{-2(1+x)yi}{2(1+x)^2-2y^2} $$

According to Wolfram

$$Re=\frac{x^2+2x-y^2+1}{((x+1)^2+y^2)^2}$$
$$Im=\frac{-2xy-2y}{((x+1)^2+y^2)^2}  $$

So the numerators agree, but not the denominators. I seem to have been adding when I should have been multiplying.

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate.

Comment: Actually, WolframAlpha *does* separate this into real and imaginary parts. Look for **"Alternate form assuming x and y are real"** in the answer.

Comment: After your edit: wrong. You have written that the real part equals $1/2$. However, with $y=0$ and $|x|\neq1$, it's obviously wrong.

Comment: @Dale.I suggest  multiply not adding, see my answer,

Comment: @AdiDani I wasn't really sure how to multiply so many parts. Thanks for demonstrating how. You seem to have multiplied the real parts and then the imaginary parts. I think that is what Jan Eerland was trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because denominator is$$(1+(x+iy))^2=((1+x)+iy))^2=(1+x)^2+2(1+x)yi-y^2$$
just multiply by $$\frac{(1+x)^2-y^2-2(1+x)yi}{(1+x)^2-y^2-2(1+x)yi}$$

EDIT:
$$\frac{(1+x)^2-y^2}{((1+x)^2-y^2)^2+(2(1+x)y)^2}+\frac{-2(1+x)y}{((1+x)^2-y^2)^2+(2(1+x)y)^2}i$$

Answer (score 2):

When $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\frac{1}{\text{z}}=\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{\text{z}\overline{\text{z}}}=\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{\left|\text{z}\right|^2}=\frac{\Re\left[\text{z}\right]}{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}-\frac{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}\cdot i$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 1) Expand the denominator and write it in the form $a+ib$. 2) Then multiply through by the complex conjugate, i.e. $\frac{a-ib}{a-ib}.$ This makes the denominator real. Now repeat 1), but this time for the whole expression.

Answer (score 1):

Square the denominator to get it into the form

$$\frac1{a+bi}$$

Then multiply be the conjugate:

$$\frac1{a+bi}\frac{a-bi}{a-bi}=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}$$

Thus, the real and imaginary parts would be given as

$$\text{Real}=\frac a{a^2+b^2}$$

$$\text{Imaginary}=\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$$